# Django: How to fix NoReverseMatch

Tags: python, django

I have a minor issue and I am stuck about how to fix it.

In my project, a user can add a post article and add an item product each is a different app with different models and they can be the same user.

I am trying to add a link to go to Item model related to a specific user (designer) if available from a page with the list of Posts of this particular user (designer).

So, in the 1st app called Score with a Post model, there is UserPostListView list view, I have my posts looped related only to a designer name. I want to add a link another page related to the items of this particular designer.

My goal is to check if there is an item related to the designer in the User Post list page, I keep getting `NoReverseMatch`

Here is the models.py

```
class Post(models.Model):
    designer = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Here is the views.py

```
class UserPostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = "user_posts.html"
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    queryset = Post.objects.filter(admin_approved=True)
    paginate_by = 6

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = get_object_or_404(User, username=self.kwargs.get('username'))
        return Post.objects.filter(designer=user, admin_approved=True).order_by('-date_posted')
```

Here is the urls.py

```
app_name = 'score'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', PostListView.as_view(), name='score'),
    path('details/<slug:slug>/', PostDetailView.as_view(), name='post-detail'),
    path('user/<str:username>', UserPostListView.as_view(), name='user-posts'),
    path('<slug:slug>/update/', PostUpdateView.as_view(), name='post-update'),
    path('<slug:slug>/delete/', PostDeleteView.as_view(), name='post-delete'),
    path('<slug:slug>/add_comment/',
         PostCommentCreateView.as_view(), name='post-comment'),
```

Here is the template user_posts.html

```
{% if item %}
 <a class="primary btn-lg" href="{% url 'core:designer-posts' item.designer %}" role="button">Go to items</a>
{% else %}
  <a href="{% url 'core:designer-posts' item.designer %}">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Go to items</button>
  </a>   
{% endif %}
```

here is the item models.py

```
class Item(models.Model):
    designer = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

here is the designerlist views.py that I am trying to link to from the user post view if it is available

```
class DesignerPostListView(ListView):
    model = Item
    template_name = "designer_posts.html"
    context_object_name = 'items'
    paginate_by = 6

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = get_object_or_404(User, username=self.kwargs.get('username'))
        return Item.objects.filter(designer=user).order_by('-timestamp')
```

Here is the urls.py

```
app_name = 'core'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', HomeView.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('user/<str:username>', DesignerPostListView.as_view(),
         name='designer-posts'),
```

Comment: You realize there's no difference between the two if's and `item.designer` will always be empty string in the `if not item` case?

Comment: @Melvyn sorry its a typo

Comment: @Melvyn are there anything codes missing or need more explanation?

Comment: You'll need to post your urls, as well. I'm guessing item.designer is meant to be item.designer_id in your url tag

Comment: Building on the previous comment, your links would look like `<a href="{% url 'core:designer-posts' item.designer_id %}">`

Comment: @Shane I have posted the urls

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's a lack of information here, but:

```
{% if item %}
 <a class="primary btn-lg" href="{% url 'core:designer-posts' item.designer %}" role="button">Go to items</a>
{% else %}
  {#                                    DOES NOT EXIST #}
  <a href="{% url 'core:designer-posts' item.designer %}">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Go to items</button>
  </a>   
{% endif %}
```

The else case always will generate a NoReverseMatch if your view expects a designer identifier of some kind.

The then case will also generate one, since `item.designer` is a model instance, not something you can stick into urls. You will need to provide what the URL expects here and @Ben makes a good guess that it it the primary key, which you can do in three ways:

- `item.designer.pk` - always works
- `item.designer_id` - relies on absence of `db_column` argument to `ForeignKey`
- `item.designer.id` - relies on primary key being a field called 'id'

Comment: I have tried them but they all returned `Reverse for 'designer-posts' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['user/(?P<username>[^/]+)$']`

Comment: Did you try those in the else clause of the template? As noted, in this case there is no item, and therefore no designed object can be accessed. If you're trying those in the if portion, it should work.

Comment: @Shane sorry but I don't understand what you mean

Comment: In your if block of the template, that's when you know you have an item. So your url call will be "OK" there - OK in the sense that an argument will exist. Whether it's the right argument...it may not be based on the urls you've posted, but that's a different issue.

In your else block, you would not have an item, and so `item.designer` would return nothing. That's likely where the reverse is failing.